# How access root element in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to modify a CSS variable contained in `:root{}`. I have tried two options:

```
componentDidMount(){ 

A) 

if (typeof window !== "undefined" ) {
    console.log("typeof window: ",typeof document)
    let document = document.documentElement;
    this.setState({document})
}    

B)

if (typeof document !== "undefined" ) {
    console.log("typeof document: ",typeof document)
    let document = document.documentElement;
    this.setState({document})
 }    
}
```

they both returns:

> _document is undefined

How make this work?
any hint would be great, 
thanks

Comment: Where this code is put? Is it even executed?. The code by itself is fine, but the question is at what point of component lifecycle does it live

Comment: thanks for answer :), they live in componentDidMount(), seems to me when the component is mounted it should mean the DOM is here, hence the window too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your variable declaration from document to something else, e.g.

```
let doc = document.documentElement;
```

I think your declaration is getting hoisted (see: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-variable-hoisting-differentiating-between-var-let-and-const-in-es6-f1a70bb43d) so when you actually log `typeof document` it actually refers to to your `let document =` and not the global document

What your code actually looks like is:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" ) {
    let document;
    console.log("typeof window: ",typeof document) // when this looks for document it is going to look in the current scope which is the one defined above, which is undefined at the moment
    document = document.documentElement;
    this.setState({document})
}
```